# How to create a field editor for Promo Image Field in sitecore 9.0.1

Tags: sxa, sitecore-client

I am using Sitecore 9.0.1 with SXA 1.7. By default the SXA Image component comes with a field editor button to add link to an image.
Can anyone please explain how this can be achieved.

[image]

The default Promo component image field doesn't have that button to add the link.

[image]

Created a new Custom button in Custom Experience button under core db after that added this new button to my sxa component.Button is appearing but when clicked it is showing empty fields.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The image component has an `Experience Editor Button`.  If you check the item `/sitecore/layout/Renderings/Feature/Experience Accelerator/Media/Image` you will see that the field "Experience Editor Buttons" there has a selection "Edit Image". This is the button that is added in the XP editor.

You can achieve similar functionality with Edit Frames (edit frames can be added through the variants).

More information on both options can be found in this blog: https://himynameistim.com/blog/custom-experience-buttons-vs-edit-frames-in-sitecore

From that blog:

> To set up a custom experience button:
>
> - In the core database navigate to /sitecore/content/Applications/WebEdit/Custom Experience Buttons and
>   create a new item based on Field Editor Button.
> - On your button item make sure you set an icon and the list of fields the button should allow the content editor to edit. These
>   should be pipe separated.
> - Switch to the master DB and navigate to the rendering item for your component
> - In the field for Experience Editor Buttons select the new button

**Update**

In the Fields section of the button you have to add the exact names of the fields you want to add. As far I can see in the screenshot, you didn't use the names of the fields of a Promo template so that is the reason the editor is blank (the fields you added do not exist in that context)

Comment: Followed your steps but not able to see the fields which i have added in the field editor button it is showing blank. Added the scrnshots in the question @Gatogordo

Comment: Added to the answer..